# How do I download an image url from axios data response using VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, axios, vue-resource

After I loop through the data in the front-end with Vue I am able to display the images but I do not know how to download it. I want to be able to click on either the image or a button in other to download the image.

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="data in mydata" :key="data.id">
      <img :src= "data.url" alt="image" class="img-thumbnail"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean "download it"? Why can't you right-click "Save image"?

Comment: I want to have an onclick function either on the image or a button that can download the image instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `download` attribute of `<a>` element:

```
<li v-for="data in mydata" :key="data.id">
  <a :href="data.url" download>
    <img :src="data.url" alt="image" class="img-thumbnail"/>
  </a>
</li>
```

But note that IE and Safari don't support `download`
https://caniuse.com/#feat=download